# python use multiple values in multiple function

Tags: python-3.x

How to do something like this in python

```
def func1():
    x = 2
    y = 3
    return x, y

def funcx():
    print(func1().x)

def funcy():
    print(func1().y)
```

So basically return multiple values from a single function then use each returned value in a different function

Comment: Just as any other [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: @usr2564301 thanx for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python functions can return only one value, but it is easy for that value to contain others. In your example, `func1` returns a single tuple, which in turn contains two values.

```
>>> def func1():
...     x = 2
...     y = 3
...     return x, y
...
>>> func1()
(2, 3)
```

You can index or unpack this return value just like any other tuple:

```
>>> func1()[0]
2
>>> func1()[1]
3
>>> a, b = func1()
>>> a
2
```

You can use indexing also in your desired functions:

```
def funcx():
    print(func1()[0])

def funcy():
    print(func1()[1])
```

If you desire *named* fields, you can use a `dict` or [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
# dict
def func1():
    return {'x': 2, 'y': 3}

def funcx():
    print(func1()['x'])

# namedtuple
from collections import namedtuple

Point2D = namedtuple('Point2D', ['x', 'y'])
def func1():
    return Point2D(x=2, y=3)

def funcx():
    print(func1().x)
```