# Output of a function in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have defined a function as below:

```
def Example(M):
......
.....

return A,B
```

M, A and B are matrices. The function returns A & B. At some point in my code i need only A. How to retrieve only A or B if required. I have tried Example(M).A but it throws error: Tuple object has no attribute A.

Comment: `A,B = Example(M)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python use multiple values in multiple function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248467/python-use-multiple-values-in-multiple-function)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thank You A, B=Example(M) is the best way solution in this scenario

Comment: As an addition: In case you know upfront you only need the first one, you can ignore the second one by using `A, _ = Example(M)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `A, B = Example(M)`.

You should also be careful about the indentation of your `return` statement. It should be indented once to the right.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a `tuple`, which is just a sequence of values with no names.

To reference the n-th value (0-based) in a tuple `x`, use `x[n]`

```
X = Example(M)
A = X[0]   # 1st value
```

However, if you have a function returning a sequence of values, you can use multiple assignment like this:

```
A, B = Example(M)
```